# Why does my entire home network go down when I change my server's network settings?

Tags: networking, routing

How do I make sure my router (not my server) controls the entire network?

I am attempting to create a bridge to bridge my two server's network cards. Every time I attempt to change anything in my network configuration *on the server*, my entire home network is taken down. I mean everything in the house, from cell phones to laptops to PC's, all lose connection until I either disconnect the server from the network or put the configuration back to its original state. Also, the change I make to the server also breaks the server's networking/internet connection, until I return it to its original state.

Clearly, my router is relying on my server for something, but I don't know what or how to go about finding it. And I surely didn't set that up on purpose.

On a side note, every change seems to require a server reboot which takes about 12 minutes, so experimenting is very time consuming and has made this difficult to figure out.

Here's a basic layout of my home network:
[image: Basic layout of my home network]

I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but I have given my server a static IP via my router:

**ROUTER SCREENSHOT**
[image]

Some other miscellaneous points which may or may not be relevant:

1. I installed **avahi** in order to be able to call my server by *servername*.local
2. The server works great, as long as I don't mess with the networking (nextcloud, webmin, phpmyadmin, all work great)
3. My home network includes MOCA devices which I did not put in the diagram

EDIT:

Some additional screenshots that could be useful:

**SERVER SCREENSHOTS FROM WEBMIN**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm going to ask a silly question so please bear with me. I can see your router is configured to serve DHCP. Are you sure your server isn't mistakenly configured to do the same. Similarly, has your server unintentionally started declaring it's the authoritative DNS server for your LAN? Look on one of your other devices - one that fails when you change the server configuration. What's its default route? What's its DNS server? What is its DHCP server? On Windows you can get this with `IPCONFIG /ALL`

Comment: When I run ipconfig /all on my Windows 10 PC it shows the router's IP: DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Comment: Which of the screenshots are for your router and which, if any, are for your server?

Comment: Are both your server's network cards connected to the home network? If so, whenever you create a bridge between them you'll create a loop. Don't do that. If you want to build in redundancy in case one stops working, look at bonding instead

Comment: I updated the post with labels of where the screenshots came from.

Comment: @roaima - I plugged both network cards into the home network and attempted to create a bridge. So, that was a mistake? I'll check out "bonding".

Comment: Attempting to use directly two NICs in the same IP LAN (as seen in the last screenshot) won't work correctly by default. Attempting to configure your server as bridge and plugging it on a switch (those LAN ports on the router are switched/bridged) can create a loop if both aren't using STP. The loop will hang the router. Anyway the output of the GUI doesn't help much to know what happens

Comment: To understand why loops are bad and why it is knocking your router out, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_storm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both of your server's network cards are connected to your home network. When you create a bridge between them you are creating a loop, which can indeed take down the network.

If you're looking to build in some form of redundancy so that either NIC can stop and the server's connectivity will continue, look up "bonding" instead of a bridging.

Once you have your bonded NICs, probably named as `bond0`, you can bridge it for your VMs on the server in the normal way

Comment: After creating a bond, can a bridge be added to allow the usage of KVM (virtual machines)?

Comment: Finally, something worked! I looked up "bonding" and followed the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding, and it is working perfectly! Webmin shows the same IP for bond0, eno3, and eno4, which is probably what I want. I chose "bond-mode balance-rr". To experiment, I pulled the plug on one of the ethernet cords and it automatically switched to a single network card. I think this is a success. Thank you!

Comment: @Benthink yes, you can bridge bond0 to some VM interfaces if you want. Just don't try to bridge two NICs on the same physical network segment :)